# OrderBy(propertyName) for complex types

Tags: c#, linq

I have

```
class User
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class Example
{
    public virtual User user {get; set; }
}
```

they are 1..N relation and I'm using EF and that all works fine, but I want to do

```
var model = examples.OrderBy("user.Name");
```

where examples is IQueryable of Examples and I get error that Example has no property of user.Name. Why is that? Can I specify my compare rules for class User? I tried implementing ICompare and IComparable with no success.

EDIT: 
this is the extension for orderBy, how can I modify it to be able to use it for my example

```
public static IQueryable OrderBy(this IQueryable source, string propertyName)

{

    var x = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");

    var selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.PropertyOrField(x, propertyName), x);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(

        Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { source.ElementType, selector.Body.Type },

             source.Expression, selector

             ));

        }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward:

```
examples.OrderBy(x => x.user.Name);
```

Should work just fine.  However, normally `OrderBy` does not consume a string -- is there a reason you were leveraging that syntax?

Comment: I have table and column names as string and I need to sort by those names, I know I can use the above code with a lot of ifs but I want to know why my code isn't working.

Comment: I just realized it's an extension someone wrote in our project. I'll edit question

Comment: @Medo, the extension method you are leveraging does not support dot-notation.  In particular, `Expression.PropertyOrField(x, propertyName)` only goes one level deep.  Have you considered using a more full-fledged API like [dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)?

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
That's what I get when I try 
examples.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x,null))
and I tried propertyInfo with DateTime and my User class,same error in both cases

Comment: @Medo, `examples.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x,null))` will never work, because `propertyInfo.GetValue` cannot be translated into SQL.  You will have to try a different approach, such as what I mentioned last time about dynamic LINQ.

Comment: It's trivial once you use a library such as dynamic LINQ.  Once you do so, the syntax would be what you'd expect, `examples.OrderBy("user.Name")` (or, more dynamically, `examples.OrderBy(propertyName)`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

`List<User> SortedList = examples.OrderBy(u=>u.Name).ToList();`

You must be using Linq